# Bootstrap 4.3 navbar dropdown list and hamburger menu not working

Tags: css, node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

I copied the navbar code from the bootstrap website but the dropdown list and hamburger menu is not working.I have tried adding popper.js and meta tags to the code as referred in some stackoverflow answers, but it did not work.

> It's an ejs file

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  

        <title>Social media</title>  
        <script
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
                crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="/scripts/index.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
                        <div class="container">
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                </button>

                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                        Dropdown
                                                        </a>
                                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                                                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                                        </form>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </nav>
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap.js was missing... it works with that now... added: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

working **snippet** below:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/index.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                        Dropdown
                                                        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add **bootstrap.min.js** file, just add the file and done.

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bootstarp.min.js for working with bootstrap.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```